# sql select doesn't work

Tags: sql, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2016

I'm using Microsoft Access 2016 in my asp.net project.
I have a yes/no field called isAdmin, and i want to make a sql that will show all users that are administrators. I tried "select * from table1 where isAdmin='1'.", but it didn't work. It gave me an error message:"data type mismatch". What should i change in the code?

Comment: what is datatype of `isAdmin` column ?

Comment: Yes/no data type

Answer (score 1):

MS Access stores yes/no fields different from standard SQL servers, even the MS SQL Server, where boolean values are 1 or 0. In MS Access the `BIT` datatype, which is the boolean yes/no field, is represented by -1 (true) or 0 (false). The negative value -1 has a bit pattern with all bits set. You would write the `WHERE` clause as

```
WHERE isAdmin = -1
```

To be more portable to other SQL databases, you can also use

```
WHERE isAdmis <> 0
```

The latter one is correct for MS Access as well as for MS SQL Server or most other SQL dialects.

See also https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-check-box-control-to-show-Yes-No-values-4FA55FFF-B3A0-4D03-A7A6-A2CFE4D03D4C

Comment: Thanks. Or: `Where isAdmin = True`. Interesting, though. I've never seen five additional answers, all wrong, to one question before.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your data type. If the data type of this column is varchar then

```
select * from table1 where isAdmin = 'yes'
```

and if it is int type then

```
select * from table1 where isAdmin = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you should try:

```
select * from table1 where isAdmin = 1;
```

Comment: That what i did and it told me "data type mismatch in criteria exeption". But when i tried to do an update query that also set isAdmin to 1 it worked. So i didn't get what i did wrong